# "Cannot access a disposedObject" exception in Xamarin when attempting to send a byte[] to server

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, xamarin

The old version of this question got too long so by the end of numerous attemts to solve this issue I came up that all can be taken down to a simple question. Why does this produce a SystemObjectDisposed.

```
    private async void PickPhotoButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            _globalStream = await DependencyService.Get<IPicturePicker> 
               ().GetImageStreamAsync();
            _globalArray = StreamToByteArray(_globalStream);

            var gal = new GalleryResource()
            {
                Pic = _globalArray
            };

            MemoryObjects.CurrentGallery = gal;
            var ctr = HelperMethods.GetInstance<GalleryController>();
            await ctr.Post();


     }

    public byte[] StreamToByteArray(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The stream arrives from the native side, I turn it into a byte array and pass it into my repository. Everyting work with a dummy byte array so something is wrong with the stream object that possibly gets closed or disposed at point.

The exception is thrown in the repository at this point:

var response = await _client.PostAsync(endPoint, _repService.ConvertObjectToStringContent(obj));

ConvertObjectToStringContent(obj) - not this part of it. From here it actually returns with a value and the byte array is seen inside the debug ie. the byte array stay with a valid lenght all way through.

The only event that does take place when we do finish picking the photo from the library is the following:

```
        void OnImagePickerFinishedPickingMedia(object sender, 
           UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs args)
        {
            UIImage image = args.EditedImage ?? args.OriginalImage;

            if (image != null)
            {
                // Convert UIImage to .NET Stream object
                NSData data = image.AsJPEG(1);
                Stream stream = data.AsStream();


                // Set the Stream as the completion of the Task
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                taskCompletionSource.SetResult(null);
            }
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
        }
```

However it doesn't seem to dispose the stream and even if it did we already got a byte array from it.

---

Tried even doing this inside Native code

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
                var c = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                c.Add(new StreamContent(image.AsJPEG(1).AsStream()));
                var response = await client.PostAsync(Settings.EndPoint + "api/gallery/", c);
```

Same error.

Comment: So which stream does the exception point out? I  believe its the _globalStream, correct? So something to fix in the GetImageStreamAsync() method.

Comment: Yeah, looks like ImageSource.FromStream(() => _globalStream) from the PickPhotoButton_OnClicked closes the stream when it gets the source for the pic to be displayed.

Comment: You might find confirmation on this in the source code of xamarin. Mhh I don't see a nice way to deal with this right now.

Comment: Oh well, thanks anyway, I edited the question a little to make it more clear and short. Apparently the error still comes up even if you stick the controller Post method right at the point where you select the pic from the library.

Comment: But for people to solve this, it's important to know where the SystemObjectDisposed exception is thrown. Do you know the exact line?

Comment: Yes, it is thrown in the repository right, at the point where it is sent via Http var response = await _client.PostAsync(endPoint, _repService.ConvertObjectToStringContent(obj));

Comment: And assigning a `byte[]` that was created in the scope of the `PickPhotoButton_OnClicked` method to the `Pic`-Property of `var gal` doesnt throw this exception?

Comment: Yeah, I mean it gets assigned fine at that point. The funny thing is that even if you debug this untill the repository Post method, even inside the repository method it actually shows a valid byte[] object with  length of 620998.

Comment: Mhh do you then change the page or dispose the Image that takes the stream for the ImageSource? So it is indeed the image disposing the _globalStream

Comment: Well the only place that it also visits after the picture is picked is the event handler. I added its code above but it doesn't look like it disposes the stream. Even if it did we already have a byte array made from it which actually stays valid untill the very end so this is all very mysterious.

Comment: I'd probably do this a bit different. Why not return the NSData as a byte array, by using the ToArray method on NSData. Also, could you post the StreamToByteArray method?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, going to try that. StreamToByteArray method added to question. Thanks.

Comment: No, I tried it with passing the array straight out of native. Gives the same exception. Very strange this it.

Comment: Btw, did u resolve this? I had to solve a similiar issue, i guess i could provide u one but not in the coming days sadly

Comment: Yeah, gonna publish a solution soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, although this issue did come up in the first place with the CrossMedia plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin it did the same error.

However the error only comes up if you for instance pick a photo like this:

```
var _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
```

So, when I did this:

```
var _mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new 
Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
        {
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small,
            CompressionQuality = 90,
        });
```

The error went away. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies somewhere in this line `_byteArray = ToByteArray(_array);`

`ToByteArray(stream)` seems to return you the byte array maybe via conversion from a stream, and this stream might still have a reference to the bytearray. And it might have become disposed.

If it's inside this method, please post it, I wanna knowww

I'm not quite experienced enough to exactly tell what it is about, but maybe my suggestions will be hitting the right spot!

Btw your code looks real clean, I like it!

Comment: Hey thanks, I actually think so too, it looks as if the stream is not copied to a new object and when it is disposed at some stage it affects the the whole chain. I will explore this further on very soon and post here where it takes me.

Comment: Looks like the stream gets closed and thats the reason. The first exception wasn't very explanitory but  did some more research and got a more explanatory exception which said "Cannot access closed stream". Now gotta figure this one out.